# Inverting alpha of BufferedImage

Tags: java, graphics, colors, bufferedimage

I'm trying to invert the alpha of a bufferedimage, but instead of inverting the alpha, it returns a strange yellow image.

This is the original before inversion [image: original]

This is what it returns: [image: return]

```
public void invertAlpha(BufferedImage lightmap){    
    int[] values = (int[])lightmap.getRaster().getDataElements(0, 0, lightmap.getWidth(), lightmap.getHeight(), null);
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) values[i] = (byte)(invertAlphaofPixel(values[i]));

    lightmap.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, lightmap.getWidth(), lightmap.getHeight(), values);
}
public int invertAlphaofPixel(int value){

    byte R = (byte) (value & 255); 
    byte G = (byte) ((value >> 8) & 255); 
    byte B = (byte) ((value >> 16) & 255); 
    byte A = (byte) ((value >> 24) & 255);
    A = (byte) (A ^ 0xff); //basically A = 255 - A I believe?

    return A | R | G |B;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return A | R | G |B;
```

The values `A`, `R`, `G` and `B` are all bytes, so the result of 'or'ing them together is a byte, which then gets sign-extended to an int.  You have to rebuild the int ARGB value the reverse of the way you took it apart, with shifts and ors.

As your code stands, the end result will most likely look like this:

```
0xffffff??
```

where the `??` is the "or" of the values.  I.e. it will be full-intensity red+green (whence the yellow) with a little variation in the blue channel but probably most bits on as well.

What you want is

```
return ((int)A)<<24 | 
        0x00FF0000 & ((int)B)<<16 | 
        0x0000FF00 & ((int)G)<<8  | 
        0x000000FF & ((int)R);
```

Also, from the output, I suspect your image is type `TYPE_INT_ARGB` and not `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`.